# Configuring prometheus to access another cluster that applications deployed

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus, grafana, kubernetes-helm

I am newbie for using monitoring tools such as Prometheus in k8s..We have two separate cluster one for applications we deployed one for we only would like deploy monitoring,logging tools.

But I have some confusion how to handle this?

1.How cluster that serves prometheus can connect to application cluster and able to pull metrics?

2.How should I specify the namespace if I would like to set a network policy?

3.What should I do in application side for helm chart except exporting metrics?

```
# Allow traffic from pods with label app=prometheus in namespace with label name=monitoring
# to any pod in <YOUR_APPLICATION_NAMESPACE>
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: monitoring.prometheus.all
  namespace: <YOUR_APPLICATION_NAMESPACE>
spec:
  ingress:
  - from:
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          name: monitoring
      podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          app: prometheus
  podSelector: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that what you want?

1) [Prometheus federation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/)

> Prometheus federation is a Prometheus server that can scrape data
>   from other Prometheus servers. It supports hierarchical federation,
>   which in our case resembles a tree.

A default version of the Prometheus server is installed in each one of our clusters and a Prometheus federation server is deployed together with Grafana in a central monitoring cluster. Prometheus federation scrapes data from all the other Prometheus servers that run in our clusters. For future expansion, a central Prometheus federation can be used to scrape data from multiple Prometheus federation servers that scrape data from groups of tens of clusters.

More info here: https://developers.mattermost.com/blog/cloud-monitoring/

2) [Prometheus configuration to scrape Kubernetes outside the cluster](https://gist.github.com/sacreman/b61266d2ec52cf3a1af7c278d9d93450) yaml example

3) Linkedin [Monitoring Kubernetes with Prometheus - outside the cluster!](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/monitoring-kubernetes-prometheus-outside-cluster-steven-acreman) article and Reddit  [Monitoring K8s by Prometheus Outside Cluster](https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/c3gc39/monitoring_k8s_by_prometheus_outside_cluster/) related discussion

Comment: that might be helpful actually..ı guess we need to install only prometheus server each of cluster no necessary to install alertmanager and grafana am I right? And we need to expose each prometheus server via ingress and using this on prometheus federation.

Comment: sure, install only prometheus if you dont need grafana, etc

Comment: How can I handle alert manager? I mean where should I setup this?